# Concentric circles vs. Parallel circles

Tags: geometry

I was recently reading about parallel lines which by definition are lines on the same plane which never meet and are equidistant. I came across a piece of text where the concept of parallel lines was also extended to curves which is all right.

My question is that can two concentric circles also be considered as parallel?

Is there something known as "parallel circles"?

Answer (score 0):

A circle is also a curve, a *closed curve*, indeed so why not?

In this link, red circle's parallel curves are shown and it also can be helpful: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleParallelCurves.html. And I also suggest you to look at this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelCurves.html